# Why do we need diodes to build an AND gate?

Tags: diodes, logic-gates

If I connect resistors to the positive and negative terminals of the battery and pretend that the terminals are as shown in the *No-Diode Circuit*

The truth table for this circuit will be:

input1,input2,output; 0,0,0; 0,1,0; 1,0,0; 1,1,1;

which is the same as the AND gate.

So Why do we build the **AND gate** with diodes?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP2zgy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The diodes isolate the inputs from each other.

Comment: If both inputs are different, can you see the short circuit between them, without diodes?

Comment: Are we supposed to know what R1 and R4 are?

Comment: Sorry I was editing the question.

Comment: Ok, so you edited your post to put resistors instead of a plain wire on the second diagram, but you also moved R5. Do you see that now, whatever the inputs, the light will be on? I'm downvoting because it makes even less sense and, moreover, you're changing the original intent.

Comment: @dim The resistors are supposedly 100 ohms the current will not flow throw the lamp if either of the inputs is connected to the negative terminal.

Comment: Well, no. Check what you did. Look where is the 12V source, and where is R5.

Comment: I will rethink about the question.

Comment: @dim I have edited the diagram just now and tested it and it worked.

Comment: It works if you say that the 'zero' state is when the input is left unconnected. But this is *not* the same as when the input is tied to ground. And, usually, logic uses two states being "input at ground voltage" and "input at supply voltage". Input left unconnected is not a valid state. Now, try to have one input tied to ground and one input at the supply voltage (be sure to check your supply has short-circuit protection first!).

Comment: Also, you have to admit that you shouldn't edit your questions in this way. Look at Andy's answer, for example. Does it still makes sense with your last edit? When you ask a question, use edit to correct mistakes, or clarify things, but make sure answers that have been posted still make sense. Otherwise, just accept that the initial question was crap and ask a *new* question. Look: although I'm quite sure my previous comment actually clarifies your root problem, I can't put it in an answer, because you're changing your question constantly.

Comment: I just asking about the idea not the circuit. My basic idea is that we can make gates without diodes.

Answer (score 2):

What you are inferring is that with out diodes you will be limited to using what is commonly called an open collector driver.  And what you are building is a wired AND gate.  That is to say that both open collector drivers have to be not-connected-to-ground in order for the lamp to operate.

With the diodes you can use more conventional drivers. I think totem-pole is the term used.  Such drivers will drive their outputs both high and low.  As pointed out in the comments, without diodes there is the possibility of creating a short circuit using such drivers.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The alternative circuit you have shown WILL NOT work because all that your inputs do is pull current from the 12 volt voltage source without altering that source. In other words, the lamp stays on regardless of the inputs.

So, when you use diodes (and the correct schematic) you don't form potential dividers because the diodes (as far as logic is concerned) can be regarded as *ideal*.

Diodes also isolate one input from another because they are, in effect, placed back-to-back with respect to the cross-couple of any two inputs.

Comment: Sorry about this and I have edited the circuit.